# How NOT to pass a parameter by URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url-routing, parameter-passing

First sorry for my bad english, i'm french. I'll try to make me understand :)

I'd like to pass a parameter from view to controller **without** using the url.

Parameter is a userid and I don't want somebody change it manually in the url.

---

My code in view :

```
  <% foreach (var item in ViewData["ClientsList"] as List<SalesCoverseal_V2.Models.Customer>)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Editer", "ClientEdit", new { id=item.PersonId }) %>

          <%: Html.ActionLink("Faire une offre", "Index", new { controller
= "Offer", id=item.PersonId }) %>
```

In controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            if (currentLoginUser != null)
            {                
                CurrentCustomer = WebService.GetClientInfos(id);
                SessionManager.CurrentCustomer = CurrentCustomer;

                OfferViewModel viewmodel = new OfferViewModel();

                return View(viewmodel);

            }


My url : 

> http://localhost:50905/Offer/Index/WS00000401

But I don't want this url, I want 

> http://localhost:50905/Offer/
```

---

Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the id in the url you are going to have to 'post' the request i.e. submit a form.
You could do this by placing the id in a hidden field. You should be aware that this by itself is not tamper proof.
If you want to ensure your user id has not been tampered with then you are going to have to encrypt it before sending it to client and then decrypt it when it is returned in such a way that you can check to see if it has been altered in any way. 
In addition you can mark your Action method as only accepting Post requests to prevent any one from trying to access it with a Get request.

Comment: I've thought, but when I use FormMethod.Post, my parameter isn't passed in [HttpPost] in my controller.

Comment: When you use FormMethod.Post all your form values are passed within the request in a form collection (instead of the url as querystrings). On the server model binding is then used to map these values to you action parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If that is part if the current user's identity, a cookie of some kind would seem the normal approach, but cookies are trivial to spoof unless you make their content either a cryptographically signed value, or an opaque unpredictable lookup (Guid) to some value. In either case you would also want to make it time-bound to prevent replay.

If you just don't want data on the URL a POST may help, but you can't redirect to a POST.

Answer (score 1):

Using a POST instead of a GET isn't really going to help fix your problem because anyone can fake a POST nearly just as easily as a GET.

I would suggest you check server side if the user has permission to view the data or not.

What is it exactly that you are trying to do? You could possibly use a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

HTHs,
Charles